# Updating xml content in twb file format with sed

Tags: bash, shell

Im working with tableau deployment and currently im looking at how i can change all my report xml file on specific content

In my linux server , my files hierarchy is as shown below. all twb files are in folder1 folder

```
- folder1
  - file1.twb
  - file2.twb
  - file3.twb
  - mylogo.png
```

twb file is nothing but a xml file . What i am trying to achieve is that i want to change to edit only twb file for all 3 files using bash/shell scripting without using any 3rd party library

original twb example.

```
..
..
<environment>
 ..
 <zone extension_url ="dev.helloworld.html>"
 ..
   <path param ="dev.helloworld.html">
   ..
 ..
 <environment>

 <referenced-extensions>
    <referenced-extension>
      <manifest manifest-version='0.1'>
        <dashboard-extension extension-version='0.1.0' id='extensions.exportPDF'>
          <author email='helloworld.com' name='mm13854' organization='helloworld' website='https://dev.helloworld.com' />
          <source-location>
            <url>https://tableau/ExportDEV.html</url>
          </source-location>
         </dashboard-extension>
      </referenced-views>
    </referenced-extension>
  </referenced-extensions>
```

example twb end result for all 3 files

```
..
..
<environment>
 ..
 <zone extension_url ="uat.helloworld.html>"
 ..
   <path param ="uat.helloworld.html">
   ..
 ..
 <environment>

 <referenced-extensions>
    <referenced-extension>
      <manifest manifest-version='0.1'>
        <dashboard-extension extension-version='0.1.0' id='extensions.exportPDF'>
          <author email='helloworld.com' name='mm13854' organization='helloworld' website='https://uat.helloworld.com' />
          <source-location>
            <url>https://tableau/ExportUAT.html</url>
          </source-location>
         </dashboard-extension>
      </referenced-views>
    </referenced-extension>
  </referenced-extensions>
```

The changes that was made after the modification is that zone extension is replaced from dev.helloworld.html to uat.development.html  & url tag is update to https://tableau/ExportUAT.html .

I am trying to write the logic if string = "https://dev.helloworld.html" , replace it with "https://uat.helloworld.html" for the whole twb file and replacing https://tableau/ExportDEV.html to https://tableau/ExportUAT.html

i have tried using sed cmd in bash

```
for file in *.twb
do
sed "s/<url>https://tableau/ExportDEV.html</url>/<url>https://tableau/ExportUAT.html/</url>/g" file
done
```

But this is returning error as sed: -e expression #1, char 16: unknown option to `s'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `/` clashes with the second expression, so you can use a different character:

```
sed -i \
-e 's|dev\.helloworld\.html|uat.helloworld.html|g' \
-e 's|https://tableau/ExportDEV\.html|https://tableau/ExportUAT.html|g' \
/path/folder1/*.twb
```

`-i` will edit all `.twb` files in place. It's not POSIX, but should be available on Linux (GNU sed). You can use `-i.bak` to backup the originals.